# How do I do full text indexing on 2 MySQL columns?

Tags: mysql, database, indexing

I have 2 columns: first_name, last_name. That's it.

When a user searches for a name, I want both columns to act as one. (as a full name).

So when someone searches for "Alex Johnson", I want it to query both columns as if they were one column.

Answer (score 0):

Will something like this help:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table_name ADD FULLTEXT(first_name, last_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concat the columns together to search on them such that a simply query would look like this:

```
create temporary table test(n1 varchar(10), n2 varchar(10));
insert into test values('tommy','bobby');

select * from test where n1+n2='tommybobby';

+--------+--------+
| n1     | n2     |
+--------+--------+
| tommy  | bobby  |
+--------+--------+
```

Full more advanced Full Text searching it sounds like you want to use the Match function.

```
SELECT n1, n2 FROM test
WHERE MATCH (n1,n2)
AGAINST ('+tommy +bobby' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

See [MySQL FULLTEXT Indexing and Searching](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/477.cfm) for more info.
*edited because I forgot about the minimum word size.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use concat in your query.

like:

```
select conact(first_name, last_name) as fullname from ...
```

detailed description you will find here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat